# Cancelling Google Wallet subscription

Tags: android-pay

This is a basic functionality of subscription so I must be missing something!
How can I programmaticaly cancel a Google Wallet subscription? Obviously when the user cancels their account with our service we need to cancel their subscription, instead of having to ask them to go to their Google Wallet console and cancel it themselves or us having to do it manually for every cancellation from our console?

[EDIT] Just to clarify, the question is about Google Wallet subscriptions (digital goods)
See above note, as I understand the only way for a cancellation of payment is a manual one, so when a user cancels our service they either have to go and cancel the payment themselves, or for us to do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Users can view the status of all of their subscriptions and cancel them if necessary from the **My Apps** screen in the Play Store app. Currently, the In-app Billing API does not provide support for programatically canceling subscriptions from inside the purchasing app.

More details can be found at [Subscription Cancellation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question was about Google Wallet for digital goods subscription, not In-App Billing subscription, but it looks like that also has the same problem!

Comment: Google Wallet for digital goods subscription still have NO api to cancel subscription pragmatically.